# Moving files into new folders AND reassigning path

Tags: html, css, visual-studio-code, filepath, file-move

I'm new and don't really know how to phrase my question.

so in VSCode I'm trying to learn how to organize my files better.

I created new folders called Views, Styles and Img. Then I moved my loginform.html files into views, loginform.css into styles and the pictures into Img folder.

Now that means since I moved the html, css and images into views, styles and img folders I need to rewrite or reassign the code path in the html for any images or css links.

For ex the html file with img tag now reads  (I added the Img folder path)
But the ouput still is giving me a 404 message and the html is not loading

What are all the steps I need within the html and css files to take when I move files into new folders. Sorry for the long explanation, I couldn't think of a way to shorten it lol

Answer (score 0):

From what i understand your arborescence looks like this :

```
root
|Views/
|----loginform.html
|Styles/
|----loginform.css
|Img/
|----image1.jpg
|----image2.jpg
```

If you want to refer to `loginform.css` from  `loginform.html`, you'll need to write :

**`href="../Styles/loginform.css"`**

Notice the `"../"` at the beginning, which means "get out of the 'Views' folder and then go to styles/loginform.css". You can even combine multiple ../ , for example `"../../../"` goes 3 parent folders back.

Your mistake, with `href="Styles/loginform.css"`, is that there are no folder named "Styles" in your Views folder (where your HTML is sitting). You first need to get out of the Views folder.